# XML "not well-formed (invalid token)" error from FlickrApi

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, flickr

First of all : I'm using the well known (and tested I suppose) [flickrapi](http://stuvel.eu/projects/flickrapi). I was testing synchronization of flickr photos with my project and everything worked fine till I reached some specific files. Then python's xml parser failed to parse xml to string (and error from topic). Debug gave me line and column in the xml, so I've exported it to a file :

```
    <exif tagspace="IFD0" tagspaceid="0" tag="Copyright" label="Copyright">
        <raw>Â©Etienne-Follet.com</raw>
        <clean>©Etienne-Follet.com</clean>
    </exif>
```

Error is in line `<clean>©Etienne-Follet` in column `<clean`**error**`>©...` . Can anyone see anything strange in this line ? What more, every single photo from this set/author crashes. Maybe it is somehow connected with the special characters ? Here's the link to sample set that fails to parse :

http://www.flickr.com/photos/rte-france/sets/72157623592737564/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsolvable: http://bitbucket.org/sybren/flickrapi/issue/11/encoding-issues . Looks like this is a flickr's side issue and they're not going to solve it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have to encode everthing in UTF-8, so make sure it is so.